# plotting graph (plt.show()) not working after an if statement is applied

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph after checking if a column is empty and I am not sure why the graph does not show up.
Please note the graph shows up without the if statement but once I have the if it does not give me an output.

I need to group by a certain column ['TIT] to see if it is empty or not. If it is empty then graph a different column ['TIT_HAR'] instead of ['TIT']

again, originally this code worked and I was able to see the graph:

```
ax.errorbar( df_combined['DAY'], df_combined['TIT'], yerr=df_combined_std['TIT'], fmt='o', color='Black', linestyle='-')
ax.errorbar( df_combined_btch['DAY'], df_combined_btch['TIT'], yerr=df_combined_batch_std['TIT'], fmt='o', color='Blue', linestyle='-')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
ax.set_xlabel('DAY', color='k')
ax.set_ylabel('TIT', color='k')
plt.show()
```

BUT once I added the IF statement it does not show anything anymore.

```py
df3=df2.groupby('XX')['TIT'].apply(list).reset_index(name='TIT')

if (len(df3.loc[0,'TIT'])==0):
    print('TIT_HAR')
    ax.errorbar( df_combined['DAY'], df_combined['TIT_HAR'], yerr=df_combined_std['TIT_HAR'], fmt='o', color='Black', linestyle='-')
    ax.errorbar( df_combined_btch['DAY'], df_combined_btch['TIT_HAR'], yerr=df_combined_batch_std['TIT_HAR'], fmt='o', color='Blue', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_xlabel('DAY', color='k')
    ax.set_ylabel('TIT', color='k')
    plt.show()
elif:
    print("TIT")
    ax.errorbar( df_combined['DAY'], df_combined['TIT'], yerr=df_combined_std['TIT'], fmt='o', color='Black', linestyle='-')
    ax.errorbar( df_combined_btch['DAY'], df_combined_btch['TIT'], yerr=df_combined_batch_std['TIT'], fmt='o', color='Blue', linestyle='-')
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    ax.set_xlabel('DAY', color='k')
    ax.set_ylabel('TIT', color='k')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't tell where or whether `ax` has been created properly.  Also, a line with only `elif:` would show an error, as it isn't proper Python code. You might want to change it to `else:`.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. (silly of me to put elif :) )